# All Free champions

Tags: league-of-legends

So at the moment i know that we can get 5 free champions:

- **Alistar** with skin **Unchained** (Subscribe LoL on Youtube)

[image]

- **Tristana** with skin **Riot Girl** (Like LoL on Facebook)

[image]

- **Garen** with skin **DreadKnight** (follow LoL on Twitter)

[image]

- **Warwick** with skin **Grey** (Refer 3 friends (they much reach lvl10))

[image]

- **Twitch** with skin **Medieval** (Refer 5 friends (they musch reach lvl10))

[image]

**Question**

Are these the only champions/skins you can have for free?

Comment: I think these 5 are the only ones currently available. Pool party is going though, and if we reach enough points we will get a mystery champion and Mundo + skin for free.

Comment: @Izzo reach enought points? which points?

Comment: You currently obtain points by winning premade matches with 5 people, and also by gifting things to others. http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/page/features/team-up-pool-party

Comment: Riot gave out Kayle in season 1, so it was free for me. In general, any time you get a skin and don't have the champion, you will get the champion as well. Mystery skins cannot give you a skin for a champion you don't own, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the only skins (and champions) you can get for free at any time. There are however some skins that are gifted at certain events. Right now  there is a community event that rewards every player with a Pool Party Mundo skins if the community  reaches 55 Million points through winning matches and gifting skins.

Other than that Riot skins exist that are often given away for free at major events where Riot is participating (Gamescom, Pax, etc.).

For ranked players above gold there has been a Victorious skin every season so far and it's almost certain that this season it will be the same but the champion hasn't been confirmed yet.